# How to find the radius of the circle after adding the area of segment?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles, problem-solving, area

I am making a game where a circle can hit a wall an interact with it to simulate a ball hitting a wall.

When the circle is 1/4 the radius through the wall the area of the part in the wall will be added to the area of the part outside the wall, thus increasing the radius of the circle to adopt for the area been added.

The area of the part outside of the wall (big circle) has to be the same as the area of the small circle.

In the image the wall is represented by the vertical line.
The distance from the wall and the centre of the circle does not change because the circle does not move it just changes shape.

Given the radius (r) and the distance (h) from the wall.
What will be the radius (R) of the new bigger circle?

[Graph example](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gdkymrfs42)

[Image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWJjS.png)

Comment: You know after a line goes through a circle it splits it in two parts. I want to add the area of one part to the other.

Comment: "after adding the area of the small segment to the area of the larger segment"  I have no idea what this means.  Please rewrite this in a way that makes sense.

Comment: " I want to add the area of one part to the other."  That just be the area of the original circle wouldn't it?  Try harder.  I still have no idea what you mean.

Comment: If you add the area of the small segment to that of the larger, then of course you get the area of the whole circle. From this it is easy to get the radius, so maybe you mean something else?

Comment: Look at the graph example how it grows when you slide the line. (It is not the correct radius just an example)

Comment: Yes the area of the new bigger part will be equal to the area of the small circle. Now i want the radius of the new bigger circle.

Comment: What's the relationship between the large circle and the small circle? It's really unclear what you're asking.

Comment: The larger circle has the larger part equal the the are of the small circle and the distance between the center and the line does not change

Comment: This problem comes from the fact that if you push the circle like it was a ball it will create a new circle where the area of one part of the big circle would be the same of of the are of the circle before pushing (pushing the circle does not change the are just the shape)

Comment: But in your graph example, the shaded area of the large circle is far greater than the area of the small circle. What do you mean when you say that those areas are equal?

Comment: That graph is just an example the new radius is wrong because my solution is wrong!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90640/discussion-between-mariksel-azemaj-and-theophile).

Comment: [![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEZYv.jpg How do the areas A (red) ,B (green),C (yellow),D (blue) relate to each other?  Does B + C = D?  Or  does B = D?  Or what?

Comment: A+B=pi * r^2.     D = B.     C = don't care

Comment: With that cleared up, it will be very helpful if you edit your question to explain the problem precisely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think an analytical solution exists for $R$. But you can use the equation for the area of an [annulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annulus_(mathematics)) sector to get a good approximation.

The area of the [segment](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircularSegment.html) of the small circle is given by:

$$A_1 = r^2 \cos^{-1}(\frac{h}{r})-h\sqrt{r^2-h^2}$$

where the angle of the segment is given by:

$$\theta = 2 \cos^{-1}(\frac{h}{r})$$

In the diagram below we see an annulus sector which approximates the area we are looking for.

[image]

The area of the annulus sector is given by:

$$A_2 = \frac{2\pi - \theta}{2}(R^2-r^2)$$

Setting $A_1 = A_2$ and rearranging the three formulas, we have the following approximation for the radius of the large circle:

$$R \approx \sqrt{\frac{A_1}{\pi - \cos^{-1}(\frac{h}{r})}+r^2}$$